# Css Conditional on IE

Tags: html, css

I want to say something like

```
#mydiv { background-color: (IE ? red : blue) }
```

I believe this can be done with conditional comments but it will be ugly. Is there some other hack that is cleaner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you can get much less "ugly" than this:

**Inside  CSS file for all browsers:**

```
#mydiv { background: blue }
```

**After you have included that CSS file:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv { background: red }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Of course, you can load a whole new stylesheet for IE.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest, least hacky way that I've seen to solve this is to ALWAYS load a special stylesheet specifically for various versions of IE.

Put all of your IE Version specific styling in those files. It may not look elegant at first but as you add more and more IE Version specific rules...it makes things infinitely easier.

...not to mention that you don't have to worry about browsers changing the way they handle the various loopholes people use to implement IE hacks.

Comment: do you mean have a stylesheet for "all" browsers with background-color: blue, then load another stylesheet ontop of that one with background-color: red (if IE)? If that is what you mean, how do you get around getting rid of a style you don't want in IE that is in your "all" stylesheet?

Comment: @Joda Maki: You would have to override this style inside your IE stylesheet back to it's default IE value. If you let us know which style you would want to get rid of in IE, we can tell you how.

Comment: You'd just reset it in your IE specific stylesheet, i.e., if some div is blue, but in IE you want it red, you simply say it so in IE specific sheet, and make sure that first the "main" css is loaded, and IE specific css after it... Other than that, it doesn't get much cleaner than Justin's proposal

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the way that [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses:

html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

css:

```
#mydiv { background-color: blue; }
.ie7 #mydiv, .ie6 #mydiv { background-color: red; }
```