# Conditional In-Line CSS for IE and Others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I was looking at the source code for [this](http://www.onlycoin.com) site.  As you scroll down, the page changes based on your current scroll position - makes for a nice effect.

Looking at the source for the page in FireFox, I noticed they use `-webkit-transform:matrix(a, b, c, d, 0, 0);` to handle the movement of the divs.  However, when viewing the same source in IE, it appears only as `transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, 0, 0);`  These style attributes are *in-line* and appear as the following:

FireFox:

```
<div class="card gift" style="z-index: 0; -webkit-transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, 0, 0); right: 198px; top: 323px; opacity: 1;"></div>
```

IE:

```
<div class="card gift" style="z-index: 0; transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, 0, 0); right: 198px; top: 323px; opacity: 1;"></div>
```

In all the previous examples, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all dynamic variables based on the current scroll position.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740591/css-conditional-on-ie) post on SO regarding conditional CSS, but they do not mention *in-line* styles, as shown in the code above.

Is such a thing possible to do?  I've tried the following, to no avail (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyT8F/)):

```
<div class="testing" style="<!--[if IE]>background-color: #321;<!--[if !IE]> -->background-color: #F00;<!-- <![endif]-->"></div>
```

If *in-line* conditional CSS is not possible, then how are they changing the in-line styles based on browser?  My best guess is JavaScript to add the properties after the page loads, as a function of scroll position.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the link provided, they include

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="no-js lt-i10 ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

at the top of their page, which is almost identical to one of the answers in the SO link I provided.  But I'm not really sure what those lines of code do.  Is this part of the solution?

Thanks again.

Comment: [if gt IE 9] .. does IE10 support conditional comments?

Comment: No. IE9 was the last IE to support Conditionals, AND the IE Hacks too many people became accustomed to using... they too are no longer valid.

Comment: The site isn't using any sort of in-line conditional. They're using some server side or client side processing to detect the browser and change what inline styles get applied to the `card gift` class elements that get those styles you see. Still, interesting find. +1

Comment: It's more likely that the inline styles were being applied by javascript.

Comment: you know which browser you're in right? so just apply only the styles needed.

Comment: @dandavis that isn't a solution, because not EVERYONE will be using the same browser as me.  I don't develop sites for only myself to view.

Comment: no no no, hear me out: the javascript which applies those inline styles to the page knows what browser your're in, and it applies only the correct settings. This is a JS question right? (the rules are not in the html source, so i assumed so) typically, only scripts set inline style attribs these days: most humans avoid such nonsense.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.  Thanks for clarifying.  And I agree, you can probably count on one hand the number of times I have intentionally used inline styles.  Your argument definitely strengthens the "it's done in JavaScript" stance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `NO`, You can't use `Conditional-CSS` as in-line.

But If you want to specify css-style according browser, here some css-hacks available:

[Css Hacks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/)

[Browser specific CSS-Hacks](http://browserhacks.com/)

Comment: Thanks.  When IE is so notorious for being a pain in the butt, I'm not sure why they continue to make it such a chore to develop for.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionals are `HTML` not `CSS` that said, I am pretty sure you cannot do inline conditionals as you have shown.

The `HTML` redirects users to specific style sheets to handle the IE side of the world, since IE is the *only* browser that supports these conditional statements.

Most likely there is a script that is detecting the browser, and updating the code on the fly as needed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought was happening.  In the edit I added to the question, what are those first five lines of code dealing with IE?

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like inline conditional css, only ie has conditional statements upto IE9, onlycoin uses javascript to achieve the inline css.