# Javascript inside an html comment

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I am writting an email with html, and in the email, I have sections I only want to show in specific browser/email clients, and for that I am using comments.

Is there a way to have a javascript selector for elements with a specific class, inside the html comments. The javascript code is not in the comments.

Here's a test example of the html I want to run my script on

```
<div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <div>This appears in Outlook</div>
        <div class="test"></div>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

And a test script

```
$(".test").html("This is a test");
```

I already tried this, and when looking at the email in outlook, the result looks like

```
This is a test
This appears in Outlook
```

Instead of

```
This is a test
This appears in Outlook
This is a test
```

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**

Turns out I got everyone confused, understandably. I am not including the script in the email. The script is being run before, it helps create the HTML from a template. The result of that is then sent as an email.

So, what i'm really asking for, is simply a way to have my javascript access elements that are inside a comment. It doesn't really matter that it's in an email. I only mentionned the email to give context as to why I need the comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: majority of the e-mail clients will not execute javascript, thanks god

Comment: The commented out code elements are not elements in the DOM to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Mail clients do not allow JavaScript in messages. It allows potentially harmful content, such as code for a hacker to steal browser cookies. Most e-mail clients do not like HTML messages either.

So, don't use HTML mail, just stick with regular mail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute code (e.g. JS) within email clients. Perhaps some dinosaur email client used to allow that in its early versions, but since that "feature" poses security issues, no sane email client (browser or desktop based) will allow that.

My first thought went to suggest to research whether it would be possible to use conditional inline-CSS (e.g. `<div style="display:none;[some clever css that only ie will figure out then display:block]"></div> ...  followed by other per-browser DIV+inline-CSS variations here`), but that is a long shot. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466047/conditional-in-line-css-for-ie-and-others). However, even is such CSS tricks do exist, you still cannot rely on them, as you cannot know which email-client the user will use to view your messages.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, the script is not part of the email. It is run before, on a template, in order to create the actual html sent as an email.